# Configuring Shiro to allow anonymous access to resource folders (JS, CSS etc)

Tags: java, authentication, spring-mvc, shiro

I'm having a problem configuring Apache Shiro to disable anonymous access to all pages except /js and /resources because that breaks the site design and layout before the user is logged in.

My current shiro-context.xml file has the following section:

```
/**=authc
/js/** =anon
/resources/** =anon
```

This will require authentication for all pages and redirect the user to /login page, but as I previously said, it will break access to resource files. It's as if doesn't pick up the 2nd and the 3rd line instructing it to allow anon access.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I perhaps prefix the path to all secure pages with something like /secure/ and allow anonymous access to everything above that folder?

Comment: In the title I wrote that I want to allow anonymous access to resource folders. In the text I said I want to disallow access to ALL pages EXCEPT resource folders. Same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work.

Answer from the documentation:

> Order Matters!
>   URL path expressions are evaluated against an incoming request in the order they are defined and the FIRST MATCH WINS.

I restructured my definitions to look like this:

```
/js/** =anon
/resources/** =anon
/**=authc
```